# MS Excel as frontend and MS Access as backend

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Please bail me out here...I am stuck from past 12 hours in this. I am trying to make a multi-user (max 10-15 at a time) Application wherein, MS Access will be back-end and MS Excel Userform is front end.

However, got 2 problems:

1 - My userform has various listboxes to restrict input. I am using Recordset to Edit and Save values from frontend. When I populate ListBoxes with values from MS Access table for any particular record, they display it correctly. However, when trying to save/update record, I have to select all the values again in userform else, blank values flows in Table.

2 - I am unable to move record from one table to another using UserForm command.

```
con.Execute "INSERT INTO UW_HOLD_TABLE SELECT DVU_HOLD_TABLE.* FROM DVU_HOLD_TABLE WHERE (((DVU_HOLD_TABLE.UV_HANDOVER_DATE) IS NOT NULL));"
```

This query is to move all records with Date value into another Table. In above code, gives error - [MICROSOFT][ODBC MICROSOFT ACCESS DRIVER] DATA TYPE MISMATCH IN CRITERIA EXPRESSION.

However, the same query runs perfectly fine at backend in MS Access. Alternatively, please suggest if I can call MS Access Query made in Database from Excel Userform directly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you copying records as is to another table in the first place?  Better database design would probably be to either add a flag field for whatever the difference is between 'DVU' and 'UW' or just write the primary keys to the second table.

Comment: Are the data types of the two tables the same in Access?  It's possible that Access is doing an implicit datatype conversion that ODBC can't.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "changed the order of both tables".  This is likely unanswerable without seeing the database.  My guess is you're running into a problem with the poor design of DB schema.